# How can I edit and save php files with php from admin panel?

Tags: php

I need to edit php files from the admin panel. How can I do this? I've seen this in CMS like wordpress and joomla. Is there a php library or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Ace for that purpose. It is a code editor built in Javascript: https://ace.c9.io/

To read the files in and save them after editing, you can use built in PHP functions like `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
    file_put_contents('myfile.php', $_POST['code']);
}
$code = htmlentities(file_get_contents('myfile.php')); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.0/ace.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea id="source" name="code" autocomplete="off" style="display: none"><?=$code?></textarea>
    <div id="editor" style="min-height: 250px"><?=$code?></div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
    var tarea = document.getElementById('source');
    var code = tarea.value;
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.session.setValue(code);
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/php");
    editor.getSession().on('change', function(){
        tarea.value = editor.getSession().getValue();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Important: Set the correct permissions for the files you want to edit.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks!